# Need to add httpd support to this wxPython code

Tags: python, wxpython, apache

I need to add httpd support to this sample wxpython code.

It parses the url and display different images.

What's the easiest way to do this?

```
import wx
a = wx.PySimpleApp()
wximg = wx.Image('w.png',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
wxbmp=wximg.ConvertToBitmap()
f = wx.Frame(None, -1, "Show JPEG demo")
f.SetSize( wxbmp.GetSize() )
wx.StaticBitmap(f,-1,wxbmp,(0,0))
f.Show(True)

def callback(evt,a=a,f=f):
    # Closes the window upon any keypress
    f.Close()
    a.ExitMainLoop()

wx.EVT_CHAR(f,callback)
a.MainLoop()
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "need to add httpd support"?

Comment: httpd, as in, Apache?  What "the url" are you talking about?  This app doesn't take any input, including any input of any url!

Comment: I want to add httpd thread to the wx program and use the web browser to remotely control which image to display.  

I now get the thread start and response to the browser, but not the internal communication with the wx program.  Somehow the "PostEvent" is not being pickup by the wx program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Need to add

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
   ....

class w_HttpThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, win):

       ...
```

On particular URL, do wx.PostEvent to the wx windows.

wxWindows code will update the window with new image.

It works too.  Love python!